# What is the probability that X or Y wins a match?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

Let us assume that there is a team X, who wins 70% of the time when ever they meet a team and loses 30%

Then let us assume that there is a team Y, who wins 60% of the time when they meet a team, and loses 40%

If team X and team Y faces each other, what are the probabilities that X wins or Y wins? Is there a formula for this, and if so, where can I read about this?

Thank you very much for helping out :)

Comment: There's no way to pin down an answer without assuming things not in your question. Under various assumptions a variety of answers consistent with this information are possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the bayes theorem, we are after the probability that X wins given the fact that Y is the opponent. Let's mark it $P(X|Y)$

$P(X|Y) = \frac{P(Y|X)p(X)}{P(Y)}$. We can't calculate the condition probability directly but we only know the ratio between them

$\frac{P(X|Y)}{P(Y|X)} = \frac{P(X)}{P(Y)} = \frac{70}{60} $ i.e. the ratio of the priors.

And it is also intuitive. If we mark the probability that Y wins as k then X has 7/6k.

it means that 100 = k + 7/6k => k = ~46% and the probability that X wins is ~54%

Comment: I see. Very well simple and well explained. Thank you.